# Anonymous mail sending: Relay access denied

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, email, smtp

I have a SQL Server, and it's sending some e-mails. But now I'm sending them from code and should rewrite this functionality in code. But have no success getting

> An exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Transaction failed. The server response was: 5.7.1 : Relay access denied

Please advice, what am I doing wrong?

SQL Server mail setup:

[image]

Code mailing:

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient("15.15.15.15", 25);
smtp.Send("fasgasg@hosthere.ru", addressOfPhone, "subj", "body");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server you are trying to send the mail through is set up to deny anonymous users sending mail  (as most are, to prevent spammers for example).  It may be that you need to authenticate first, probably using the basic authentication.

Comment: You're right: I should run this code under specific user and then it works fine.